# How to put a from inside a from in html

Tags: html, forms

I am trying to put a form inside a form, here is my code:

```
<form action="info.php" method="post" id="test1">
        <input type="hidden" name="name" value="test">
        <a id="test" style="text-decoration:none;" onclick="document.getElementById('test1').submit();">
            <!-- somestuff -->
            <form action="insertCart.inc.php" method="POST" id="test11">
                    <p class="card button"><button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('test11').submit();" name="add-to-cart">Add to Cart</button></p>
                </form>
            </div>
        </a>
    </form>
```

I have tried lots of javascript with the onclick but if i click on the button that is inside the from that is inside the from it will do nothing, but if i change the type to submit it will submit the from with the id "test1" that is also not what i want.
Is there any way i can fix it??

Comment: You can't. Nested forms are invalid HTML.

Comment: Could it be that the id value of your inner form is typed incorrectly? Instead of `tset11`, it should be `test11`.

Comment: @HeisAif Don't link to duplicate answers. [Here is the original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379610/can-you-nest-html-forms) which states what I already said. The HTML is invalid.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you nest html forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379610/can-you-nest-html-forms)

Answer (score 2):

You can't nest forms, it's invalid HTML.

However, what you can do is use the `form` attribute in your inputs to create the same effect.

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/54901309/1600379:

```
<form id="main-form" action="/main-action" method="post"></form>
<form id="sub-form"  action="/sub-action"  method="post"></form>

<div class="main-component">
    <input type="text" name="main-property1" form="main-form" />
    <input type="text" name="main-property2" form="main-form" />

    <div class="sub-component">
        <input type="text" name="sub-property1" form="sub-form" />
        <input type="text" name="sub-property2" form="sub-form" />
        <input type="submit" name="sub-save" value="Save" form="sub-form" />
    </div>

    <input type="submit" name="main-save" value="Save" form="main-form" />
</div>
```

Comment: Note: the `<input>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Comment: Using end slashes, or not, are both valid HTML. Using them or not is a different discussion and not relevant to this q&a.

Comment: for what code i have it does not work and i also tried this for the button that was meant 
 to submit the form inside the form that did not work: <button name="add-to-cart" onclick="document.getElementById('test11').submit();">Add to Cart</button></p>

Comment: While it is allowed, I like to point out to people, who seem to be using it more and more for no known reason whatsoever, how useless and pointless that effort is as it carries no meaning and does nothing.

Comment: @Alien10, your code is confused, it's not only a nested form, but it's also placed within a link, which looks to be trying to do the same thing as the nested form submit button. It may be part of a wider set of code, but you may need to rethink your approach and the reason for having a nested form in the first place. Nested forms are a valid, but not common requirement. The attribute was included in the spec specifically for the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can not nest the form tag inside another form.

Answer (score 0):

I had to make the forms different forms for it to work